# Reachability change iOS system notification for suspended application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking, notifications, reachability

Is there a system network reachability notification, that sends wifi/3G change notification to application in suspended mode, so it can wake up application?
I couldn't find that topic in Apple developer guide and example code like Reachability only works when application is not suspended.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this legally. If you do find a way (by say pretending to be a VoIP application, Apple wile most likely not approve your app.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

To quote:

> This is a drop-in replacement for Apples Reachability class. It is ARC compatible, uses the new GCD methods to notify of network interface changes.
>
> In addition to the standard NSNotification it supports the use of Blocks for when the network becomes reachable and unreachable.